# Apple watch face: change from an app running on watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to change watch face from an App running on the watch? I would like to put a picture (not animation) as my watch face.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot programatically change the watch face. The only way as a developer to customize it, is to use Complications.
The only other option, which involves the user, would be to render the watch face as an image, save it in the photo library of the iPhone and ask the user to set the image as a watch face.

Comment: I know the second way, but let's go back to the Complications, Can there be an app which can fetch an image from some server and display as a watch face?

Comment: I have no experience in creating custom complications with ClockKit.  You should have a look at the Video explaining how to create them from this years WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-209/